# Apache Camel: set boolean header using simple contains

Tags: apache-camel, boolean, spring-dsl

Is there any way to set header with boolean value for checking contains like this.

```
<setHeader name="status">
    <simple>${headers.type} contains 'client'</simple>
 </setHeader>
```

This should set status as true if type contains client else false.

Comment: According to the documentation https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html


And an example with contains, testing if the title contains the word Camel
`simple("${in.header.title} contains 'Camel'")`

Comment: @R.Groote  I tried this but its not storing boolean value into  header. it gives me values like client contains 'client'.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html#_setting_result_type), you need resultType

```
<setHeader name="status">
    <simple resultType="java.lang.Boolean">${headers.type} contains 'client'</simple>
 </setHeader>
```